# When are the units of R[x] exactly the units of R?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

I (Anton) have edited this question to be the question Pete and Zeb discuss in the first few comments.

> What conditions on a ring $R$ imply that the units of $R[x]$ are exactly the units of $R$?

Comment: As with your last question, this is an undergraduate level homework-type question, hence not what Math Overflow is designed for.  (Also, please don't use the "math-education" tag as a synonym for "Help me with my math questions".)  But here's a hint: for any commutative ring R, show that the units of R[x] are precisely the units of R.  

Comment: Your hint is kind of false. Let R = k[e]/e^2, then in R[X] we have (1+eX)(1-eX) = 1-e^2X^2 = 1, and 1+eX, 1-eX are not in R.

The hint becomes true if the ring R is an integral domain. (Does anyone know if there is a weaker condition we can impose on R making the hint true?)

Comment: @ZC: Thanks!  I should have said integral domain (e.g. Z!).  Also, it is very tempting for me to edit the question to put your last question into it: it would make for a much better MO question.  

Comment: Actually, Pete, I'm not sure about your hint.  What about $R = \mathbb{C}[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$?  Then $\epsilon x - i$ is a unit of $R[x]$.

Another, more immediately useful, hint since I'm feeling bighearted: if R is a domain, then the degree of a product of polynomials in R[x] is equal to the sum of the degrees of the factors.

Comment: P.S.: "Kind of false"?!?  What, is that supposed to make me feel better? :)

Comment: Or: what they said while I was typing slowly.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that "zeb" should be getting the credit here. By the way, is this Zeb Engberg?

Comment: If you're using commutative rings with unity, then you can just require the ring is reduced; see exercise I.2 in Atiyah & Macdonald.

Comment: Pete said, *"Also, it is very tempting for me to edit the question to put your last question into it: it would make for a much better MO question."* I think that's a good enough idea that I'm willing to hijack the question and do it (with apologies to Huey).

Comment: +1:  I'm voting up Huey. He should get some credit for the interesting exchange of ideas he initiated.

Comment: @Georges: He should get +1 for failing to do the first part of the second exercise in a completely standard book on commutative algebra?? What is this site coming to! [or perhaps I missed part of the question?]

Comment: @Kevin: No, you missed nothing. As I said, I thought his question initiated a great exchange of comments and a great answer.And even a professional mathematician of the highest calibre could make a small mistake about the exercise, which proves that it is not trivial. I suppose Huey is a beginner and I thought I could encourage him. But obviously judging from the fact that he has been downvoted again I am in a minority (or alone) to hold that opinion and I bow to the majority.

Answer (score 25):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then by the following result, the answer is "if and only if $R$ is reduced."

> If $R$ is a commutative ring, then $a_0+a_1x+\cdots + a_nx^n\in R[x]$ is a unit if and only if $a_0$ a unit in $R$ and $a_i$ is nilpotent for $i>0$.

*Proof*. One direction is easy. Any polynomial of the given form is a unit because the sum of a unit and a nilpotent element is always a unit.

The other direction isn't too hard if $R$ is a domain (the product of non-zero elements is always non-zero). If $g=b_0+\cdots b_mx^m$ (with $b_m\neq 0$) is the inverse of $f=a_0+\cdots+a_nx^n$ (with $a_n\neq 0$), then the highest order term of $1=f\cdot g$ is $a_nb_mx^{n+m}$, so we must have $n=m=0$ and $a_0$ invertible (with inverse $b_0$)

For the general case, suppose $a_0+\cdots +a_nx^n$ is a unit. Reducing modulo $x$, we must get a unit in $R[x]/(x)\cong R$, so $a_0$ must be a unit. Reducing modulo any prime $\mathfrak p\subseteq R$, we get a unit in $(R/\mathfrak p)[x]$. Since $R/\mathfrak p$ is a domain, the previous paragraph shows that $a_i\in \mathfrak p$ for all $i>0$ and all primes $\mathfrak p$. Since the intersection of all primes is the nilradical, each $a_i$ must be nilpotent.

---

A more "bare hands" elementary proof is given in [Ex. 1.32 of Lam's Exercises in Classical Ring Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=S3pZbAByfDgC&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=&f=false). He also gives counterexamples to both implications if $R$ is not assumed commutative and mentions a really interesting related question. If $I\subseteq R$ is an ideal all of whose elements are nilpotent and $a_i\in I$, then does it follow that $1+a_1x+\cdots +a_nx^n$ is a unit in $R[x]$? If you can prove that it does, it would imply the [Köthe conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6the_conjecture), a famous problem in ring theory.

Comment: +1: way to make lemonade.